# Efficient search in a array of obj in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

let's say i've a preordered array of object such as this one:

```
let data = [
    { moment: '00:01', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '01:10', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '05:37', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '07:51', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    //and so on
]
```

I've got in input x which is formatted as an hour:minutes string (ex. x='06:05') and i need to find the two consecutive objects (data[i] and data[i+1]) such that data[i].moment <= x < data[i+1].moment

Suppose the array has almost 200 elements and i need to fastest way to find the results. Do i've to implement the binary search from scratch? is there a library i can use?

Comment: https://github.com/darkskyapp/binary-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i've to implement the binary search from scratch?

what's the point? it's just a few lines of code:

```js
let data = [
    { moment: '00:01', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '01:10', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '05:37', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    { moment: '07:51', otherProp: 'something', somethingMore: 'someelse'},
    //and so on
];
let search = '06:05';

let lo = -1, hi = data.length-1, mid;
while(hi > lo){
  if(data[mid=(lo+hi+1)>>1].moment > search) {
    hi = mid-1;
  } else {
    lo = mid;
  }
}

console.log(data[lo]);
console.log(search);
console.log(data[lo+1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: What about cases where `search` is less than the first value, greater than the last value, or equal to a value of the array?

Comment: @RobertBaron it's fine since i just want to know how to theoretically do it, i can manage those edge cases by myself.
Thomas this was my first thought too, i just wanted to be sure there is not better (maybe cleaner) solution, thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobertBaron What if you'd have checked and seen that all theses cases are already covered?

Answer (score 1):

```
var pos = data.indexOf(data.find(function(obj) { 
    var value = (obj.moment.split(":")[0]*60) + (obj.moment.split(":")[1]*1)
    var key =(search.split(":")[0]*60) + (search.split(":")[1]*1);
    return (key < value);
   }));

pos = pos >= 0 ? pos : data.length

data.splice(pos, 0, {moment:search, otherProp:"something", somethingMore: "someelse"});
```

This would work.